# Laravel subquery query

Tags: sql, laravel

I want to use subquery in query as select. But this code doesnt work.

```
$listed_waiting_approach = DB::table('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners')
    ->join('be_product','be_product.id','=','be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.product_id')
    ->join('be_status','be_status.id','=','be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.payment_status_id')
    ->where('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.is_approved','=',false)
    ->where('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.is_active','=',true)
    ->where('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.payment_status_id','=',$payment_status_id1)
    ->where('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.order_status_id','=',$order_status_id1)
    ->select('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.*','be_product.name as productname','be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.is_approved as approve','be_status.code as statuscode','**(SELECT code FROM be_status WHERE id=$payment_status_id1 ) as paymentname**')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DB::raw combine with a DB::select. That is something like

```
DB::select( DB::raw( " ... ") )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [selectRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#selectraw):

```php
DB::table('be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners')
    ->selectRaw("be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.*, be_product.name as productname, be_medical_insurance_for_foreigners.is_approved as approve, be_status.code as statuscode, (SELECT code FROM be_status WHERE id={$payment_status_id1}) as paymentname")
    ->get();
```